# Lock android phones to default wallpaper

Tags: android

I'm not sure if this qualifies, but I'm trying to figure out how to lock a number of android phones to a defualt wallpaper and screensaver akin to computers at a workplace. Any help would be apprreciated.

Comment: Custom launcher maybe?  Not a dev question so probably better to ask over at https://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thanks for that, i'll asl over there